# What is this houseplant with dark green linear leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I can't seem to identify this little guy.

[image: Plant]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like a not terribly well Asplenium nidus, common name Birds' Nest Fern. It may be yours is suffering from insufficient light as well as a dry atmosphere, they do like a lot of humidity, so bathrooms and kitchens are often good places for these. In terms of light, bright daylight is best - a little winter sun won't do any harm.

Some care instructions in the link below

http://www.houseplantsexpert.com/birds-nest-fern.html

Comment: Thank you. Any advice on how to get it to take its expected shape?

Comment: yea - increase its light levels (but no sun), raise the humidity around it. If you've got the plant in an office (I can see monitors) then you'll have to use a pebble tray - a tray twice the size of the pot, filled with pebbles, half fill with water, stand the pot on top so its not actually touching the water. Does best in temps of 70-80 deg F, feed with half strength liquid fertiliser during the growing season (spring through to early summer), twice weekly.